# sun.net.www.http.HttpClient memory leak in Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, httpclient

I'm using **Tomcat 6.0.18**. After undeployemnt of my app, *HttpClient* appears to be holding a reference to *WebappClassLoader*, hence causing the memory leak.

After some investigation, I've found solution in **Tomcat 7.0.6**, [JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_6/java/org/apache/catalina/core/JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java) with **keepAliveProtection** attribute. But this approach is not working with **Tomcats 6** (I've customized JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener, in order to add support for this attribute).

Does anybody have a solution how to fix this leak in Tomcat 6?
Thanx!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted, otherwise the question will remain open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution for memory leak.

One must make implementation of [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListen), as following:

```
package org.example;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
         tomcatLeakPreventionForHttpClient();
    }

    private void tomcatLeakPreventionForHttpClient() {
        try {
            final Field kac = HttpClient.class.getDeclaredField("kac");
            kac.setAccessible(true);
            final Field keepAliveTimer = KeepAliveCache.class.getDeclaredField("keepAliveTimer");
            keepAliveTimer.setAccessible(true);

            final Thread t = (Thread) keepAliveTimer.get(kac.get(null));
            if(t.getContextClassLoader() == Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()) {
                t.setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
            }
        } catch(final Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }

}
```

and, of course, to register listener in *web.xml*:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.example.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```